# Does the sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor support sparse input samples?

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scipy

I’m using `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor` on data that is sometimes lacking some values. I can’t easily impute these data because they have a great variance and the estimate is very sensitive to them. They are also almost never 0.

The [documentation of the `fit` method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.fit) says about the first parameter `X`:

> The input samples. Internally, it will be converted to dtype=np.float32 and if a sparse matrix is provided to a sparse csr_matrix.

This has lead me to think that the GradientBoostingRegressor can work with sparse input data.

But [internally](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/ensemble/_gb.py#L1441) it calls `check_array` with implicit `force_all_finite=True` (the default), so that I get the following error if I put in a `csr_matrix` with `NaN` values:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

Does the GradientBoostingRegressor not actually support sparse data?

Update:

I’m lucky in that I don’t have any meaningful zeros. My calling code now looks like this:

```
predictors['foobar'] = predictors['foobar'].fillna(0) # for columns that contain NaNs
predictor_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(
    predictors.values.astype(np.float)
)
predictor_matrix.eliminate_zeros()
model.fit(predictor_matrix, regressands)
```

This avoids the exception above. Unfortunately there is no `eliminate_nans()` method. (When I print a sparse matrix with `NaN`s, it lists them explicitly, so spareness must be something other than containing `NaN`s.)

But the prediction performance hasn’t (noticeably) changed.

Comment: Sparse matrix is just another [efficient] representation of an array with many zeros. If you have NaNs, sparseness won't help you. Anyway you have to decide on imputation strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try using LightGBM. Here is a discussion in Kaggle about how it handles missing values:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/discussion/57918

Good luck